How many parameters are stored in the flight data recorder these days?
Originally, it was seven parameters, scratched into foil tape in analog form.
Many years later, a video said it was over 100 parameters stored digitally. About 10 years ago, someone referred to it being several hundred.
How many do they store now? Do they store literally every piece of information available, including trivial things like whether the lavatory door is locked?
Is there a master list I could look at? I can't imagine it's secret.

I do not think there is a master list (aka unique list). Now it is "mostly" an hard disk: Aircraft manufacturers may include what they may think interesting. FAA have minimal requirements (depending on aircraft type) (and NTSB has additional recommendations, which I assume somebody will add as answer).

For aircraft following FAA regulations, modern FDRs for air carriers must store 88 parameters, which are listed in 14 CFR 135 Appendix D. The previous lists are in 135.152, there were 11 parameters for pre-1969 aircraft and 29 for post-1969. The list was expanded in 1991.
In reality "over 1000" parameters are actually recorded, NTSB:

By regulation, newly manufactured aircraft must monitor at least eighty-eight important parameters such as time, altitude, airspeed, heading, and aircraft attitude. In addition, some FDRs can record the status of more than 1,000 other in-flight characteristics that can aid in the investigation.

Other smaller lists can be seen in 125.225 125.226, they contain 11, 17, and 91 entries. 125 Appendix D has another list. These specify the FDR regulations for air planes, vs air carriers in Part 135.
And finally, AC 20-141B discusses the technical details of a digital FDR. There are some appendices that may be helpful, such as determining the requirements for various categories of air carriers and airplanes.
Some similar previous questions:

Is there anywhere I can pick up raw flight data recorder information?
What is the format of data stored by a Flight Data Recorder?
How much data is stored in the flight data recorder per hour in a typical flight of an A380?


GOD! I wish all answers here were as complete and great! I followed your links to discover the Fred format that's used on flight data recorders. https://papers.phmsociety.org/index.php/phmconf/article/download/1400/373 ===== THANK YOU!

It should be noted that these parameters are logged at different rates. While the basic flight parameters are logged with the highest rate possible, other less important parameters might only be logged once a second or even once a minute (e. G. Door status) in order to save data storage space
